# Continue in Python loop not restarting after try and except

Tags: python

The loop does not restart after an exception occurs in a python loop. I have tried both `continue` and `pass`. When i use `continue` the loop does not proceed forward it is stuck at the exception. when i use `pass` it captures on the the id that has the error and the the ones before that even if there is no error when i print it shows as error.

This is my code that i am using.

```
for i in ids:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
                # searching for an id.
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)            driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()
                #navigating to the profile
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
                #copying the and storing the date
            subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
            subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
                #exiting current details
            driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
            sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            continue
```

Any suggestions how do i restart the loop with the next id. The exceptions occur either above or below the search bar.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: `coninue` or `pass` (in this case) will just proceed to the next *iteration* of the loop, if you want to re-start from the first id you need to re-factor your code and wrap this all in another loop. However, I would question your approach, it seems like you are catching all errors with a blank `except Exception` and just re-running/ignoring everything, this seems naive (and bad), instead catch specific exceptions and handle them accordingly

Comment: Add print statements in all interesting places, so you see precisely what happens.

Comment: @Chris_Rands i did try to capture the errors. I have 3 errors in specific. However i wanted to add them based the id when i get these error messages. was using it like this `except Exception as e:   errors = e.parameter       error_msgs.append(errors)`  i get a message say cannot find the parameter attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Example version:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 2]
other_id = [1, 2, 3]
id_generator = (id for id in ids) # this is a generator, needs the brackets
while True:
    try:
        id = next(id_generator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    try:
        print(other_id[id])
    except Exception as e: # this will happen when id = 3, and is not a valid index in other_id
        continue
```

A version for your code

```
id_generator = (id for id in ids) # this is a generator, needs the brackets
while True
    try:
        id = next(id_generator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
            # searching for an id.
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(id)
        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()
            #navigating to the profile
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
            #copying the and storing the date
        subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
        subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
            #exiting current details
        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

Comment: I need it to go to the next  element in the loop. post continue it does not go to the next id  just stays at the id which does not have any records or not found. Sorry if i was not clear.

Comment: I made an edit to the code, this should fix that problem. You just need to turn your ids into a generator, e.g. my_generator = (id for id in ids)

Comment: Thanks for that. Could be a little more specific based on my code. That would be really helpful. I tried it `my_generator = i for id in ids`. Throws up a SyntaxError.

Comment: thanks for the code. However I get this error. `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'` .  I referred to this link as well. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).  Based on what information i get there is says the iterator is exhausted and `StopIteration` exception is being raised.

Comment: @RenLyke oops, that should be next(id_generator) if you're on python 3. Code updated!

Comment: This works amazing thanks for all the help. Just made a minor change to the code. From `send_keys(i)` to `send_keys(id)`. Thank you once again. Will run the entire list of ids to see if i get stuck with any error message.

Comment: @jingIesting I ran it on the list of 50 ids and where an id was not in the system that could not be traced. The code shut down and did not continue to the next id on the list

Comment: @RenLyke which version of python are you using?

Comment: @RenLyke please see the above. Can you confirm the simple version works on your machine (ie prints 2 3 3)

Comment: I used a print statement for my ids. If the id is not found this is the error message.  `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. //*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a`. This is also the xpath which the other ids are being used to be found.

Comment: @RenLyke 1. What happens when you run the simple version? 
2. Try replacing `except Exception as e:` with `except NoSuchElementException as e:` in your code and let me know what happens...

Comment: This is the exact error message. `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"}`

Comment: @RenLyke please look at my answer again. You may have not noticed that I have updated it, hence why you sent me the same information twice. Please let me know what happens when you run only the example version I have written.

Comment: i am using Python 3.6 via Anaconda. running the simple version that i get the values at the end 2,3,3 . I was making changes the site was not refreshed when i updated it.

Comment: @RenLyke No worries :) Did you try replacing `except Exception as e: with except NoSuchElementException as e:` in your code yet?

Comment: Yes i tried the same. When this exception arises the code stops and does not proceed to the next id. The site closes post the error message after waiting for couple of min.

Comment: @RenLyke Does it enter the exception clause before it exits?

Comment: Yes it does enter the exception clause pauses o the site. The error message gets printed multiple of times. Then it exits the site. Also i don't have `driver.quit()` function in the code for it to do that.

Comment: @RenLyke ok. I would guess that, when there is an error, something in the second try clause has been executed which needs to be "unexecuted" by the except statement. If I were you, I would use separate try/except clauses for each of the lines in your code where you are getting exceptions, and handle them individually as appropriate. If you do not, there is a risk of some broken setting being passed on to the next iteration which is causing a different problem.

Comment: What i noticed was that when the id is available this is the xpath. `//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a`. When the id is not found the xpath changes to this `//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_pnlResults"]`. Since both are different that is why i think this not working. Any suggestions how to work around this

Comment: could this issue be because i am using an absolute XPATH. Instead of a relative one. Any suggestions how to build a relative XPATH

Comment: I'm really not sure at this point Ren, good luck finding the issue. Perhaps you could try using a debugger like in PyCharm to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jinglesting. I solved it by breaking the code into sub parts by using `if` and then in `except` i redirected it to the home page.

```
for i in ids:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
            ​-    # searching for an id.
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)

        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"])./tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a')!=0:
                click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
                subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
                subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
                driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftNavColumn"]//*[text()="Home"]').click()
            continue
```

Thanks for all the help i learned something new about generators.